# Compile error using Neon in NaCl

Tags: neon, google-nativeclient

I added the command line setting “-mfpu=neon” so that I could use NEON instructions.

But that causes a weird compile error:

```
1>C:\Misc\nacl_sdk\vs_addin\examples\video_app\hello_world_gles\src\YUVBlock16x8.cpp(158,1): internal compiler error : in set_minipool_offset, at config/arm/arm.c:12961
1>   }
1>   ^
1>  libbacktrace could not find executable to open
```

If I comment out the code in the function, it compiles/links successfully.

BUT, the resulting NaCl module doesn’t load on the ChromeBook.  In the console I see:

NativeClient: NaCl module load failed: Validation failure.  File violates Native Client safety rules.

```
…

… Run sel_ldr in debug mode to ignore validation failure.

… Run ncval <module-name> for validation error details.

… reap logs
```

I haven't included the neon header or used any neon instrinsics/assembly yet.

```
C:\Misc\nacl_sdk\vs_addin\examples\video_app\hello_world_gles\NaClARM\newlib\Release>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\pepper_29\tools\ncval video_app_arm.nexe
```

Valid.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the optimization flag from -O3 to -O2 fixed the compile problem and validation problem.  My code is slightly faster, too.